# Customer account section on subdomain

Tags: customer, url, frontend

I have a single website, single store view Magento installation on, lets say, the domain example.com. Now I want to create a customer section "My Example.com" on my.example.com. So the whole customer module/section needs to go to my.example.com.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this (in a neat upgrade safe manner)?

Answer (score 1):

## Idea

### Add storeview

Add a second store (`customer_store`) view with the exact same settings as the first store view (`old_store`)

### Implement Observer to correct store

Implement Observer which checks whether the `full_action_name` in `predispatch` is `customer_*` if yes and you are not on `customer_store`, redirect.

And vice versa.

Comment: Ok, good idea! I'm going to check this... work it out a bit. I'll let you know if this is going to work for me.

Comment: maybe you don'T need the new store if you disable the redirect to homepage option and do the redirect by hand