# Bind subdomain to a Magento Controller

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, controllers, redirect, store-view

I am working on an application for which I want to create few sub-domains in system, which will be served by Magento application. One example scenario can be creating separate sub-domains for system user's profile. Where User A will have dedicated url `user-a.example.com` and user B will have a url `user-b.example.com`. Now, I want to able to map these sub-domains to a controller which will in turn fetch profile information and render it for a particular user.

My current approach involves use of `Reverse Proxy` on webserver level, where i am mapping subdomains `<USER>.example.com` to controller `http://example.com/user/profile/index/name/<USER>/`. Which works well untill i want to perfom some operation based on current url. Even though user sees url with subdomain on the page but in the background request is being made to `http://example.com/user/profile/index/name/<USER>/` and Magento system returns full url as current page url.

So, I was wondering if there is any way to bind a subdomain to controller directly in Magento system. I went through few [questions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11453/customer-account-section-on-subdomain) posted around this but those does not seems to much useful here.

Comment: You can create new store views with the specific subdomains. Depending on the count this might be a really bad idea ;-)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt, Yeah my thought also is same. System will have these urls generated dynamically in good numbers.

Comment: Mixing DNS resolving with file system requests. Gonna be a pain.

Comment: @Lalit I wonder if you're able to find a solution for your question?!

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I have only one store, I do not need a multiple store setup, but a single subdomain for some user profiles. Did you get this to work??

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet will be to use Apaches URL rewrite functionality for more information see:
 https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ 
The other option would be to write a completely new router but this will require a good understanding of request processing in Magento. https://shop.vinaikopp.com/grokking-magento/ has some very good information to help you with this.

Magento does not provide this as a standard feature and you will need to do it either via apache or by writing a Magento router.

Something that you could use would be along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %1 !=www
RewriteRule ^ /user/profile/index/name/%1/
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, I am trying do something similar with Reverse proxy approach but with this approach for Magento the current url is the new redirected url. Which defeats my purpose and hence was looking for something that Magento provides.

Comment: @Lalit I added some additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Magento rewrites instead. Im not sure if this will work, but you can give it a try.

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <designer_url>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/author/id/#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/designer/index/index/id/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </designer_url>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

See [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17018/rewrite-url-using-config-xml) question for some more info.

Comment: Thanks @mbalparda, I doubt this will handle rewrites at subdomain level. Looks like it moreover handles path redirects. Have you tried this with subdomains? does that work?

Comment: No, i did not tried this but it might worth a shot.

Comment: Please note this is deprecated functionality.

Comment: @RyanStreet please explain your comment.

Comment: This method for doing a controller rewrite is deprecated.  It is not the modern and accepted way to do rewrites in Magento 1.8 (tagged in this question).

Comment: @RyanStreet is there any documentation to back that up? What would you use to set up a rewrite via code?

Comment: Sure.  Fundamentals of Magento development course offered by Magento, Inc.  Here is a screenshot of the slide in the class: http://i.imgur.com/ROiRzbq.jpg

Comment: I don't think that rewrite and this rewrite are the same. That is a rewrite for a view and this is a htaccess rewrite with regular expressions inside a config.xml

Comment: It's the same.  Follow the post and the link to the blog.

Answer (score 0):

Since subdomains are above Magento in the grand scheme of things, `NS A Record` mapped with your name server. Then adding the mod_rewrite rule to the controller path as *Martijn Schot* mentioned would be the ideal approach.

There are other ways to facilitate this also. Such as Replication, creating a path in the file system when a customer registers, with nothing more than a redirect to the proper controller in the application.  Keep in mind this may pose scaling problems.

Another option to consider is [Wildcard DNS Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record).

SO Answer taken from:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/183971/158325

> You're looking to create a custom **A record**.
>
> I'm pretty sure that you can use wildcards when specifying A records
>   which would let you do something like this:
>
> ```
> *.mywebsite.com       IN  A       127.0.0.1
> ```
>
> *127.0.0.1 would be the IP address of your webserver.  The method of actually adding the record will depend on your host.*
>
> ---
>
> Doing it like http://mywebsite.com/user would be a lot easier to set
>   up if it's an option.
>
> Then you could just add a .htaccess file that looks like this:
>
> ```
> Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$  dostuff.php?username=$1
> ```
>
> *In the above, usernames are limited to the characters a-z*
>
> ---------- The rewrite rule for grabbing the subdomain would look like this:
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mywebsite.com
> RewriteRule (.*)  dostuff.php?username=%1
> ```