# How to route custom Magento module controller to a subdomain with Nginx?

Tags: module, controllers, nginx, domain

To simplify my question I'm going to use this [custom module example](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643) as a base for my question.

Once I implemented the custom module in the example, I was able to access `indexAction` as follow:

> http://www.example.com/index.php/mymodule/index/index

However, my objective is to access `indexAction` from a subdomain as follow:

> http://mymodule.example.com/index.php/index/index

The `frontName` is the subdomain name.

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this.

Comment: I would say you would need to do this at at the server level. Are you using Apache, Nginx?

Comment: @andrewkett I'm using Nginx. I tried doing it on server level but magento keeps redirecting to main domain. Maybe my rewrite condition is wrong. Any suggestion how it should look like?

Comment: @andrewkett I started a bounty on this [question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37479/bind-subdomain-to-a-magento-controller) since by question is marked as duplicate.